# c++ sift down heap

Tags: c++, heap, heapsort

I am writing a program that requires me to use a heap, and everything runs fine besides my sorting methods, obviously quite important! I am not sure what is wrong with my logic or if I am missing something stupid. But a fresh set of eyes to look at this would be nice.

The function is being passed my vector which is of course the heap, the location of the root, and then either the STL less or greater as a predicate.

```
template<class T,class P>
void upheap(vector<T>& v, int start, P func) {
   T x = v[start];
   while (start > 1 && func(x, v[start/2])) {
      v[start] = v[start/2]; start /= 2;
   }
   v[start] = x;
}
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: You say you're passing the root of the heap? Shouldn't you be passing the index of the element that needs to be upheaped?

Comment: sorry yeah thats what I meant its the index value.

Comment: Maybe you should write the invariants, pre-conditions and post-conditions, and then perhaps you'll see the trouble.  For example, is the condition 'HEAP(i = 0 .. start-1)' true on entry?  And then the objective is to have the condition 'HEAP(i = 0..start)' should be true on exit?

Answer (score 2):

The first element in a vector is at v[0].  You seem to assume it's at v[1].  Is there a reason for this?

If the root is at v[0], given a node at index i, the parent is at int((i-1)/2) (though (i-1)>>1 might be more efficient), and the children are at 2i+1, 2i+2. E.g.:

```
     0
   1   2
 3  4 5  6
78 9A BC DE
```

On the other hand, if the root is at v[1], the parent is at int(i/2) (or i>>1), and the children are at 2i, 2i+1.  E.g.:

```
     1
   2   3
 4  5 6  7
89 AB CD EF
```

So that could be an issue.

You check to see if ***func(x, v[start/2])*** is true.  If func is the heap condition, you may want to check if that's false...

Is the vector already large enough to include v[start]?  If  *upheap()* is being used to add items into the heap one at a time...  And the vector's size is never increased...  (Also, you are starting at v[1], not v[0].  So that's an extra element.)

Have you tried writing a simple scaffolding (code that is used for testing/debugging but not part of the final product) routine to print the heap, adding it into your loop, and running with practice data to see where things go off kilter?